# Antd table in iOS webview

Tags: ios, reactjs, webview, scroll, antd

I am creating a react app using antd in React, and it is being exposed webview in mobile application.

I set fixed options in table so that, first Column is fixed in here.

```
{
  title: column,
  fixed: 'left',
  dataIndex: 'baseRow',
  key: 'baseRow',
}
```

The problem is the scroll showed before table like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIpHC.jpg)

And it happens only in iOS webview.
How can I don't display scroll bar before the table?
And, Why does it happen in iOS webview

antd docs: https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: Can you please, provide the table code for your issue?